# javascript recursive on object never ends

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

I am having trouble with my recursive function not looping through correctly, at the bottom is my code that I am having trouble with, the stuff before that is just to show I have worked A LOT on it :) There is also a link to a working example. I was previously using a ton of nested for loops like this:

```
function assembleTimeline(targetItem, sequence) {
    var TIMELINE = "";
    var greenAniArray = {options:{}};
    for (S = 0; S < sequence.length; S++) {
        greenAniArray = [];
        for (L = 0; L < sequence.length; L++) {
            alength = greenAniArray.length;
            for (var setting in sequence[S][L]) {
                greenAniArray.push({});

                if (setting == "duration") {
                    greenAniArray[alength]["duration"] = sequence[S][L][setting];
                    delete sequence[S][L]["duration"];
                }else{
                    greenAniArray[alength].push({});
                    for (var option in sequence[S][L][setting]) {
                        greenAniArray[alength]["options"][option] = sequence[S][L][setting][option];
                    }
                }
                if (greenAniArray[alength]["options"]) {
                    delete greenAniArray[alength]["options"]["duration"];
                }
                $(".jsonresults").html(prettyPrint(greenAniArray));
            }
        }
        animationSequence = greenAniArray[alength]["options"];
        animationDuration = greenAniArray[alength]["duration"];

        // Make commands look like this:
        // to($box, 1, {x:50,y:0})

        assembledTimeline += '.to("' + targetItem + '", ' + animationDuration + ', ' + JSON.stringify(animationSequence) + ')';
    }

    TIMELINE= "tl" + assembledTimeline; 
};
```

to get through this when someone suggested a recursive function, but The "sequence" is an array that could have a single item, or dozens. I am putting this together to accept info from an array / object with an animation sequence like this one I made: http://codepen.io/ajhalls/pen/QbvRbQ

http://codepen.io/ajhalls/pen/bdrmGw?editors=101

```
$(function() {
  var target = "targetDiv"
  var aniMation = "";
  var sequence = [{
    "duration": ".2",
    "transform": "translate3d(0,0,0)"
  }, {
    "duration": ".2",
    "transform": "translate3d(0, -30px, 0)"
  }, {
    "transform": "translate3d(0, -15px, 0)",
    "duration": ".2"
  }, {
    "transform": "translate3d(0,-4px,0)",
    "duration": ".2"
  }];

  function parseAnimation(target, sequence, count = 0) {
    for (var property in sequence) {

      duration = sequence[property]["duration"];

      delete sequence[property]["duration"];
      aniSequence = sequence[property];
      //$(".output").text(JSON.stringify(aniSequence)); 
      aniMation += '.to("' + target + '", ' + duration + ', ' + aniSequence + ')';
      $(".output").text(aniMation);

      parseAnimation(target, sequence[property], count++);
    }
  }

  parseAnimation(target, sequence);
});
```

Comment: Recursive functions often break or cause a stack overflow if you fail to catch errors adn parse the perameters you feed back in to the function.

Comment: Is requirement to pass an array of settings to `parseAnimation` , which will be called in sequence as arguments to `parseAnimation` until no settings objects remain in original `sequence` array passed ? Tried utilizing http://api.jquery.com/queue ?

Comment: @dave while the duration is repeated and is the same in each of these examples, it could just as easily have had a unique value as the animation speeds up / slows down.

Comment: @Dave I am so sorry, that was a typo from copying things around, it shouldn't have had the second one and I have edited it to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need recursion for the sequence in your example.  If you have sequences that contain sequences then you would want recursion.

```
$(function() {
  var target = "target"
  var aniMation = "tl";
  var sequence = [{
    "duration": ".2",
    "transform": "translate3d(0,0,0)"
  }, {
    "duration": ".2",
    "transform": "translate3d(0, -30px, 0)"
  }, {
    "transform": "translate3d(0, -15px, 0)",
    "duration": ".2"
  }, {
    "transform": "translate3d(0,-4px,0)",
    "duration": ".2"
  }];

  function parseAnimation(target, sequence)
  {
    for (var property in sequence)
    {
      var s = sequence[property];
      var aniSequence = { "transform": s["transform"], "duration": s["duration"] };

      aniMation += '.to("' + target + '", ' + s.duration + ', ' + JSON.stringify(aniSequence) + ')<br>';
      $("#output").html(aniMation);
    }
  }

  parseAnimation(target, sequence);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Phill, the sequence could have any css property or transformation property from Greensock such as: 
`{
    left: random(300,160) ,
    top: random(300,100) ,
    y: random(100,0),
    scale: Math.random(),
    backgroundColor:"#ffcc00",
    opacity: Math.random()
  }` Otherwise it is nice.